# Firefox overflow: hidden bug

Tags: html, css, firefox

So I added in an image slider into my webdesign as it is now. It worked fine in IE + Chrome, but in firefox I had a very strange issue.. The image slider images were being pushed towards the right hand side of the page.

[image]

When it should look like this:

[image]

I really don't know why this is happening.

here is the css for the slider:

```
    <style type="text/css">
        #slider {
            position: relative;
            width: 918px;
        }
        #slider .viewer {
            position: relative;
            width: 918px;
            height: 200px;
            overflow: hidden !important;
        }
        #slider .viewer .reel {
            display: none;
            height: 200px;
        }
        #slider .viewer .reel .slide {
            width: 918px;
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
```

And the css for the container around the slider:

```
#photobox {
border-left: 1px solid #ababab;
border-right: 1px solid #ababab;
position: relative;
width: 918px;
height: 200px;
z-index: -1;
top: -6px;
}
```

This is really stumping me. You can also see a live version of the site - http://simplesolutions.netne.net/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a floating issue:

```
#slider {  float:left }
```

should fix it.

Answer (score 5):

Adding `clear:both` to `#slider .viewer` seems to take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

`Margin-top : 6px` on the #photobox fixes it in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, (Firefox only) with the same type of layout. I found the problem to be margin-bottoms on the nav menu items, pushing the content div below them, to the right.

The tricky part was that the nav menu itself didn't have any margin on the bottom, so it looked like it shouldn't have been interfering with the content below (and it wasn't in other browsers, just in Firefox) - but, at some point I realized that the list items (menu items) themselves did have margin bottoms that extended below the menu bar, and removing them fixed it.